# LDA2Vec Python implementation example?

Tags: python, word2vec, lda, word-embedding

Hi can anyone please help me with the working example of LDA2Vec using python?
Please assume dataframe df having a column "Notes" containing text data

I am trying to implement "cemoody/lda2vec" github example but getting multiple issues- 
1. how to install spacy package?
2. ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocess' from 'lda2vec'
3. ImportError: cannot import name 'LDA2Vec' from 'lda2vec'

Not sure what I am missing here.

Any help/links will be really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

in C:\Users--user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\lda2vec folder, there is a file named *init* which calls for other functions of lda2vec, but the installed version of lda2vec using pip or conda does not contain some files. 
so you have to download the zip folder from https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec and replace/add the files which are named wrong or missing in C:\Users--user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\lda2vec and moreover you may need to replace/correct/add some of the lines in *init* file as it contains spelling mistakes (for instance it calls for Corpus, but there is only corpus) and syntax errors (for example missing parenthesis for print command) as i presume it is written in Python 2.
I was correcting these mistakes since a day and I am not yet able to run the examples he provided on https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec.
Give me a heads up if you get it running after you make the changes.